# Pattern to internationalize links in JSF

Tags: jsf, design-patterns, internationalization

I want to internationalize the following content:

> Click `here` to view our privacy policy.

`here` is a hyperlink.  Here is how I currently go about it:

```
#{msg.footer_privacyPolicy1}
<h:outputLink>
    #{msg.footer_privacyPolicy2}
</h:outputLink>
#{msg.footer_privacyPolicy3}
```

`msg` is a `ResourceBundle` registered in `faces-config.xml`, with the following contents:

```
footer_privacyPolicy1 = Click
footer_privacyPolicy2 = here
footer_privacyPolicy3 = to view our privacy policy.
```

---

I think there must be a better pattern to achieving this.  Here is what I *don't* like about my approach:

- Flexibility in actual internationalization is lost, because I am constraining the semantic order of the sentence.  For example, maybe in certain languages, the imperative to "click" should go at the *end* of the sentence - but this would not be possible in my approach.
- The mechanics of the presentation (i.e. the hyperlink) are getting mixed into the content.  If I later remove the hyperlink, or use a somehow different hyperlink control, the property files would need to change as well.

Is there a better approach to internationalizing content that is necessarily partitioned by the mechanics of presentation markup?

Comment: Such links may better be placed in (internationalized as well as localized) resource bundles themselves in the form of a plain HTML anchor tag `<a>` and be displayed using some JSF output components setting their `escape` attribute to `false` such as `<h:outputText value="#{msg['key']}" escape="false" />`.

Comment: Tiny, thanks for your response.  I did consider embedding simple anchor markup.  However, I'm not sure that this is the lesser evil, compared to the original problem.  Presentation leaking into my content seems worse than breaking up a resource entry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) offers [`<o:param>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/param) for the exact purpose.

```
footer.privacyPolicy = Click {0} to view our privacy policy.
footer.privacyPolicy.link = here
```

```html
<h:outputFormat value="#{i18n['footer.privacyPolicy']}" escape="false">
    <o:param><h:link outcome="privacyPolicy" value="#{i18n['footer.privacyPolicy.link']}" /></o:param>
</h:outputFormat>
```

On contrary to `<f:param>`, it's capable of encoding child components as parameter value.

Comment: @BalusC can we do the same with `<h:outputFormat>` and `f:param` ?

Comment: @BalusC - thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!  The content and presentation are nicely separated, without partitioning internationalized text.

Comment: @Tarik: if it were possible with standard JSF, I'd have answered that and `<o:param>` wouldn't have existed.

Comment: @BalusC I just wanted to know the difference,  thanks for the update

Comment: @Tarik: there's a link behind the tag in the post.